# Why does changing XMLHttpRequest break FB?

Tags: javascript, facebook

If you go to fb or fb/messages/ and run this code (copied/paste in a console or use a userscript) the page messages up. Specifically chat window doesn't load, links don't work, you can't click middle button and scroll with it (mouse wheel still works) and scrolling up on chat doesn't load previous chat.

I expected nothing to change with the code below. As far as I know it should call whatever was set to XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open in the exact same way. Why would this code break facebook?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @namespace   mytest
// @include     https://*.facebook.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function(open) {

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
        return open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
    };

})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `this` context is changed by your script and they have something detecting that to prevent malicious script injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it is because you are passing "this" as the object on which to be bound , which is not the original XMLHttpRequest object, but a temporary object created in your scope in your function definition. So it shouldn't work. You can try creating a temporary XMLHttpRequest object and pass it in place of this, which should work.

Comment: 1) I'm a bit of a JS noob and I have no idea how to do that. 2) this code hasn't broken other sites. Eventually I'd like to write `this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function()` and console.log results of specific urls which works fine in other sites I tried.

Comment: Can you try this ? `(function() {
    var proxied = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        console.log( arguments );
        return proxied.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
    };
})();`

Comment: For me the above code is working, in facebook messenger and getting all the urls - @acidzombie24

Comment: It seems to work fine. Although I don't see the messages coming up on the console. It looks like facebook disabled it. I have no idea how to enable it. But I may pass on trying to get this to work on fb